# Issue when trying to chain promises in Angular2

Tags: angular, promise

I miss something to fully grasp the promise concept.

I try to achieve this: calling a function once my http returns, as follows

```
onSubmit(event: any) {
        this.submitted  = true;
        event.preventDefault();

        this.si
        .signIn(this.emailAddress, this.password, this.keepSignedIn)
        .toPromise()
        .next((res:any) => {
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        });
}
```

But got the error:

```
this.si
.signIn(this.emailAddress, this.password, this.keepSignedIn)
.toPromise is not a function.':
```

In the service I wrote my call as follows;

```
signIn(emailAddress: string, password: string, keepSignedIn: boolean): Promise<any> {
    console.log("SigninService, emailaddress="+emailAddress);
    console.log("SigninService, password="+password);

    const auth = this.buildAuthToken(emailAddress, password, keepSignedIn);
    const headers = this.getHeaders();

    console.log("SigninService, headers="+JSON.stringify(headers));

    const url = 'http://dev-user.zeens.ws/api/v1/me';
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers})
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
        console.log("response="+JSON.stringify(response.json()));
        this.user = response.json().result;

        console.log("response="+JSON.stringify(this.user));

        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));

        return this.user;
        /*
        console.log("signin="+JSON.stringify(response.json().data));
        return response.json().data;
        */
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers})
.toPromise()
.then(response => {
  ...
})
.catch(this.handleError);
```

In your service, you're already using `toPromise`.
As you wrote it, your function has the following definition :

```
signIn(emailAddress: string, password: string, keepSignedIn: boolean): Promise<any>
```

Then you do :

```
this.si
    .signIn(this.emailAddress, this.password, this.keepSignedIn)
    .toPromise() // <---- PROBLEM
    .next((res:any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
    });
```

**Here you to try to apply `toPromise`, on a promise.**

Currious, why do you want to convert it to a promise ?

You could simply do :

```
signIn(emailAddress: string, password: string, keepSignedIn: boolean): Observable<any> {
    ...

    return this.http.get(url, {headers: headers})
    .map((response: Response) => {
        this.user = response.json().result;

        localStorage.setItem('user', this.user);

        return this.user;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

onSubmit(event: any) {
    this.submitted  = true;

    this.si
        .signIn(this.emailAddress, this.password, this.keepSignedIn)
        .subscribe((res:any) => {
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        });

    // returning false is equivalent to event.preventDefault()
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT :**
In order to have map defined, you need to import it.
In your main.ts or somewhere loaded only once, add the following :

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Just for example, here are my imports :

```
// rxjs operators
// see node_module/rxjs/Rxjs.js
// statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
// operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/let';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/withLatestFrom';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';

// observables
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
```

Comment: Hi @Maxime, following your advise, I just switched from Promise to Observable. I added the import { Observable } from rxjs/Observable and removed the import rxjs/add/operator/toPromise. But I have a .map is not avail on Observable<Response>. Any idea?

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca yes, I edited my answer. It should be good with that ;)